# Assigning inplace pandas function to underscore

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently reading Python for Data Analysis by Wes.
There's a line of code in the book which assign a inplace rename of a df to underscore. Why? And there's also a comment atop that says Always returns a reference to a DataFrame. What does it mean?

```
# Always returns a reference to a DataFrame
In [151]: _ = data.rename(index={'OHIO': 'INDIANA'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Since within `rename`, you specified `inplace=True`, that means the dataframe is changed inplace without explicit re-assignment. Usually you don't need the `_ = ` part and only need to do `data.rename(index={'OHIO': 'INDIANA'}, inplace=True)` and it will return `None`, which is not to be used anyways. In general when you assign something to `_`, you are telling people that you are not using the returned value and it can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might help you [SO_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)
I would add that in your case the use of the special variable '_' was not necessary but maybe a way from the author to make you wonder what it is...